# How to edit a shortcut's target and launch it?

Tags: c#, target, shortcut

I looked through and couldn't find anything that addresses exactly that;

I'm using ForceBind to force a browser to use the wi-fi connection and not the Ethernet one.
In order to launch the browser using ForceBind, I'm using a shortcut of which the target field is that:

C:\Windows\System32\ForceBindIP.exe 192.168.2.91 "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.6\firefox.exe"
(I'm basically launching the ForceBind program and telling it to launch the browser)

The main issue here is that the IP address obviously changes every time I'm connecting to a wireless network (and due to reasons irrelevant to here, I can't set a fixed address to attempt to request from the router), so I wrote the below code to fetch the current wireless adapter's address:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Variable declaration
            string adapterName = "";
            string adapterIPAddress = "";
            int num = 0; //assisting var

            NetworkInterface[] interfaceList = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

            for (int i = 0; i < interfaceList.Length; i++) 
            {
                if ((interfaceList[i].NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211) && (interfaceList[i].OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)) 
                {
                    adapterName = interfaceList[i].Name; 
                    var ipProperties = interfaceList[i].GetIPProperties(); 
                    foreach (var ip in ipProperties.UnicastAddresses) 
                    {
                        if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                        {
                            adapterIPAddress = ip.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    num = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Adapter name:    " + adapterName);
            Console.WriteLine("Adapter type:    " + interfaceList[num].NetworkInterfaceType);
            Console.WriteLine("Address:         " + adapterIPAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("");

            //Create a string that represents the path with the appropriate IP Address
            ///<   C:\Windows\System32\ForceBindIP.exe xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.6\firefox.exe"   >
            string newPath = "C:/Windows/System32/ForceBindIP.exe " + adapterIPAddress + " \"C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox 3.6/firefox.exe\"";
            Console.WriteLine("New path: ");
            Console.WriteLine(newPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to launch...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            System.IO.File.Open(newPath, FileMode.Open);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh no! Something went wrong! Bummer.", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Question is, when attempting to launch (System.IO.Open...), I get an exception saying that path has an illegal character. So a. What's the illegal character and how can I launch the file, or b. if there's an existing shortcut on my computer, how do I have this program edit its target (changing just the IP address) and launch it?

Comment: File.Open() doesn't make any sense.  Did you mean Process.Start()?  If you meant to modify a .lnk file then type "shelllinkobject" in the Search box.